# How to capture the output of a Julia script while the script is running in a shell?

Tags: shell, io, julia

I can capture the output of a julia script in the shell with the > operator, for example:

`$ julia script.jl > output.txt`

However, it seems that the file is only written to after the julia script finished. For example, if `script.jl` contains the following code:

```
println("Hello world!)
sleep(10)
```

then `output.txt` is created immediately, but the `Hello world!` appears in the file only after 10 seconds.

Is there a way to immediately write the Julia output to the file as soon as each command is executed and not wait for the script to finish?

Comment: You have to turn stdout to unbuffered inside your Julia program, or - if you don't want to modify `script.jl` - run it via `stdbuf`. See _man stdbuf_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
println("Hello world!")
flush(stdout)
sleep(10)
```

So the output isn't buffered.

Answer (score 0):

For instance by

```
stdbuf -o0 julia script.jl > output.txt
```